# What is the equivalent service to Azure Queues in Google Cloud Storage?

Tags: google-cloud-storage

I am trying out Google Cloud from a .NET web app and I am looking for a queue system for background tasks.
Is there a queue service in Google Cloud Storage (similar to Azure/ Amazon AWS queue)?

Answer (score 2):

Try the Task Queue: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/taskqueue/

"With the Task Queue API, applications can perform work outside of a user request, initiated by a user request. If an app needs to execute some background work, it can use the Task Queue API to organize that work into small, discrete units, called tasks. The app adds tasks to task queues to be executed later."

Comment: Available [in python](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/queue) too

Comment: Thanks jspcal. Can I use it from a .NET Web app outside of Google's appengine?